# How do I use SQLite Database _id/value pairs in an Android Spinner while keeping the "_id" part hidden from the user?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

In my app, I have a form. Behind the form, I have several lookup tables in the database like this:

```
+-----+------------+
| _id |   value    |
+-----+------------+
|  1  | Plane      |
|  2  | Train      |
|  3  | Automobile |
|  4  | Bicycle    |
|  5  | Dog Sled   |
+-----+------------+
```

My form looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout>
        <TextView />
        <Spinner android:id="@+id/entry01" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout>
        <TextView />
        <Spinner android:id="@+id/entry02" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout>
        <TextView />
        <Spinner android:id="@+id/entry03" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

To populate my Spinners with the database data, I use the standard technique:

```
DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
String[] fromColumns = {"_id","value"};
int[] toViews = {R.id.dropdown_id, R.id.dropdown_value};
Spinner entry01Spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.entry01);
Cursor entry01Cursor = dbHelper.getEntry01Cursor();
SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.generic_dropdown, entry01Cursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0);
entry01Spinner.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);
```

My `generic_dropdown.xml` layout:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/dropdown_id" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/dropdown_value" />
</LinearLayout>
```

What I am trying to do is something like in HTML. When I select "Automobile", I want to store the value of '3' in my database for that entry. Obviously, I don't want the `_id` to actually show on my form, I would like it to be "hidden" like in an HTML form.

So, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: The question is not very clear? Can you please add a picture to show what does your spinner look like in your android application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want the _id to actually show on my form, I would like it to be "hidden" like in an HTML form

So set the visibility of the View to hidden.

```
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/dropdown_id"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/dropdown_value" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Well, that's too cool. I had no idea that option was available. Thanks.